# Evaluating order of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I think this is quite a simple question, I just want to make sure I understood all correctly.

Here's the problem: I have a numerical method, which is in some way dependent on its spacing $h$ (like pretty much every numerical method ;)).

Now I have calculated the errors of this method for different values of $h$, and I'm interested in the order of convergence.

What I've got so far: My current results always divide the spacing by 2, so $h_1 = \frac{h_0}{2}$, $h_2 = \frac{h_1}{2}$ etc.
I also have for the corresponding errors: $e_0 \cdot C = e_1$, $e_1 \cdot C = e_2$ with $C < 1$ and it is approx. constant for all steps.

So I guess in this case I have linear convergence $\mathcal{O}(h)$, right?

But my question is now: What if I don't have this relationship $h_i = \frac{h_{i-1}}{2}$, but instead use arbitrary spacings, say $h = \frac 1 2, \frac 1 3, \frac 1 4, ...$

What is my approach then to calculate the order of convergence?
Thanks

Comment: what is the ratio $h_{i+1}/h_i$?

Comment: relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence#Convergence_speed_for_discretization_methods

Comment: @newbie: I want to be general in possible, so no fixed ratio

Answer (score 1):

Plot a graph of `log(error)` vs `log(h)`. The slope of the curve gives the convergence rate. This can be easily computed using octave:

```
r=polyfit(log(h),log(error),1);
convergence_rate = r(1);
```